# Why does this simple JS promise return a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

A really simply question. I've boiled it down to the simplest version that illustrates my problem.

Why does this vanilla JS return a promise, and how can I get it to return "Hello"?

```js
    
let result = test()
  .then(function(result) {
     return result;
  });

alert(result);
    
function test(serialized) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("Hello");
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns a promise"? What behavior do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just use:- ```(async () => {
 alert(await test())
})();``` to get the result from `test`..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you are "alerting" the value returned by the `then` method.

The `then` method will always return a promise, even if you are returning a value, it's wrapped in a resolved promise (e.g. `Promise.resolve('Hello')`), this allows you to achieve *chainability*, for instance you can call and return other promises in the `then` callback, and they will wait the resolution to continue and resolve.

```js
  test()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return result + ' world!';
      }).then(function(result2) {
        console.log(result2); // Hello world!
        return new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve('End') });
      }).then(function (result) {
         console.log(result);
      })
    
    
    function test(serialized) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("Hello");
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`promise.then((result) => {})` always return another promise, so that we can chain multiple `.then()` calls.

`how can I get it to return "Hello"?` : For this you must `await` a promise.

for eg: `alert(await test())` problem is that you can use await only within an async function.

Another option is to alert within then.
`test().then((result) => alert(result))`