# Why does this javascript / firebase function return a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've been breaking my head today over this function. All I am trying to do is get all documents from my collection in Firebase and put this in an array of documents like the fakeProjectMetaData.

There's similar questions around here:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)
- [Why does this simple JS promise return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134951/why-does-this-simple-js-promise-return-a-promise)

But i just dont get it when going through my own code. I've really tried many different things programming it and deleted it, so can't show here. So I'll show what i have and what breaks my brain.

The below code is in a service file. I have imported the function in another file. I'm in React trying to use the context API & Hooks. Consider it an FYI as I don't see that relevant for the below

```
import firebase from "../data/firebase/config";

const fdb = firebase.firestore();

    const fakeProjectMetaData = [
      {
        projectID: 1234,
        projectName: "Testing 123",
        numberOfKeywords: 2109,
        scrapeFrequency: "Weekly",
        lastUpdate: "2 days ago",
      },
      {
        projectID: 4567,
        projectName: "some other one",
        numberOfKeywords: 10245,
        scrapeFrequency: "Monthly",
        lastUpdate: "Last month",
      },
      {
        projectID: 7894,
        projectName: "Creative agency version 1",
        numberOfKeywords: 105,
        scrapeFrequency: "Daily",
        lastUpdate: "Yesterday",
      },
    ];

// fake data is just to show the datastructure. It's not used now. 

export const getAllProjects = async () => {

  const allProjectData = [];
  await fdb
    .collection("fakeProjects")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((project) => {
        allProjectData.push(project.data());
        return;
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

  return allProjectData;
};
```

(Should I not use async await here maybe?) In this other file i invoke the function as follows:

```
const projectData = getAllProjects();
```

Now i realize this projectData is (still?) a promise that I have to process like this:

```
projectData.then((project) => {
  console.log(project);
});
```

Which at least outputs an array that I expect. However changing this to the below doesn't work..

```
const projectArray = projectData.then((project) => {
return project;
}); 

console.log(projectArray);
```

Very curious to your answers on why this results in a promise where I expect this getAllProjects return an array of objects. What am I missing? How to get this result from firestore as an array to work with?

Comment: What about async await?  const projectData = await getAllProjects(); . And add 'async' before a 'function' word.

Comment: "why this results in a promise where I expect this getAllProjects return an array of objects?" -> [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/8839059)

Comment: `then` and `catch` both **always** return a promise.  It's also normally a bad idea to mix then/catch along with async/await  If you're able to use async/await, just stick with it throughout your code.  await will unwrap the value from the promise so you don't need then/catch at all.  I suggest finding some good examples of code to study so you can learn how it works.